# CKEditor how to pick up what has been highlighted

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am attempting to creat an extra plugin for ck editor.

I have created a button on the toolbar and am at the stage to do something when this is clicked....

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('enlarge',
{
    init: function (editor) {
        //Plugin logic goes here.
        editor.addCommand('insertenlarge',
            {
                exec: function (editor) {

            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton('enlarge',
            {
                label: 'Insert enlarge',
                command: 'insertenlarge',
                icon: this.path + 'images/enlarge.png'
        });
    }
});
```

What I dont know is how to get the highlighted element. Basically i want the user to click on an image in the editor and click enlarge and it opens the image up in a new pop up, i just want to be able to for now find out how to access the image element so i can place it in a pop up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

`editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement()`